# htaccess use RewriteCond group matched in RewriteRule condition

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm using mod_rewrite with this rule:

```apache
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1/$2.jpg !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1/x19_$2.jpg -f
RewriteRule ^(site/views/00_projects/[^/]+/content/image/[^/]+)/([^/]+)\.(?:png|jpg|gif)$ $1/x19_$2.jpg [T=image/jpeg,L]
```

But `x19_` can be multiples values, such as `x1_` to `x19_`

Is there a way to catch `RewriteCond` group match and use it in `RewriteRule` result?

I already tried to get `(x(?:[1-9]|1[0-9])_)` from `RewriteCond` and use it on `RewriteRule` as a backreference, but it didn't worked out - it seems that neither `$` nor `%` variables gets the group :(

Comment: Do you have any other rules in your `.htaccess` file? The rule you've posted does not appear to be correct (or is incomplete) by itself. What would you expect to be the response when receiving a request for `/<url-path>/<file>.png` and `/<url-path>/<file>.jpg` exists? (A scenario that that rule specifically checks for.)

Comment: I've answered your question, making the assumption that the first condition is intended to exclude requests that already map to an existing file.

Answer (score 1):

No, unfortunately you can't do something like this in `.htaccess`. You can't test the existence of a file based on a *pattern* - which would require mod_rewrite to effectively traverse the directory to find files that match. There is no such mechanism. You need to use a separate rule for each file you want to test for - see the "solution" below.

> I already tried to get `(x(?:[1-9]|1[0-9])_)` from `RewriteCond` and use it on `RewriteRule` as backreference, but it didn't worked out - it seems that neither `$` nor `%` variables gets the group :(

The first argument to the `RewriteCond` directive (the *TestString*) is an "ordinary" string (that allows backreference/variable parsing), not a regex. So, the characters `(x(?:[1-9]|1[0-9])_)` will be seen as literal text and the condition will most likely fail.

---

> ```apache
> RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1/$2.jpg !-f
> RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1/x19_$2.jpg -f
> RewriteRule ^(site/views/00_projects/[^/]+/content/image/[^/]+)/([^/]+)\.(?:png|jpg|gif)$ $1/x19_$2.jpg [T=image/jpeg,L]
> ```

*Aside:* By itself this rule does not really make sense (or is incomplete). You are checking for `.png`, `.jpg` and `.gif` at the end of the requested URL-path, however, you are then checking whether the corresponding `.jpg` (only) file does not exist. So, if the `.jpg` file exists (even when a `.png` file is requested) the rule is not processed. Perhaps the intention is to prevent further processing if the requested file exists (which is what I will assume), but if it is then the first condition can be simplified.

---

#### "Solution"

Since there is nothing in the request that you can base the condition on you would need a separate rule for each file you want to check for, in order of priority - first match wins.

However, the multiple rules can be simplified by either failing early (if you have no other rules that need to be processed on this request) or skipping the rules when the criteria does not match.

For example:

```apache
# Skip the following 20 rules if the URL-path does not match
# (file check + x1 to x19 = 20 rules)
RewriteRule !^site/views/00_projects/[^/]+/content/image/[^/]+/[^/]+\.(png|jpg|gif)$ - [S=20]

# Abort early if the request already maps to a physical file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# Check for x1 jpg
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1/x1_$2.jpg -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)/([^/]+)\.(png|jpg|gif)$ $1/x1_$2.jpg [T=image/jpeg,L]

# Check for x2 jpg
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1/x2_$2.jpg -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)/([^/]+)\.(png|jpg|gif)$ $1/x2_$2.jpg [T=image/jpeg,L]

# Check for x3 jpg
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1/x3_$2.jpg -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)/([^/]+)\.(png|jpg|gif)$ $1/x3_$2.jpg [T=image/jpeg,L]

# etc.
:

# Check for x19 jpg
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1/x19_$2.jpg -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)/([^/]+)\.(png|jpg|gif)$ $1/x19_$2.jpg [T=image/jpeg,L]
```

The `RewriteRule` *pattern* in the subsequent rules (ie. "Check for x1" to "x19") can be simplified since we have already established in the first rule that the requested URL-path matches the required pattern.